# Prove the inclusion-exclusion formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

We just touched upon the inclusion-exclusion formula and I am confused on how to prove this:
$|A ∪ B ∪ C| =|A| + |B| + |C|
− |A ∩ B| − |A ∩ C| − |B ∩ C|
+ |A ∩ B ∩ C|$

We are given this hint: To do the proof, let’s denote $X = A ∪ B$, then
$|(A ∪ B) ∪ C| = |X ∪ C|$,
and we can apply the usual subtraction rule (you will have to apply it twice).

That just made me even more confused. I was hoping someone can guide me through this, or explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "subtraction rule" is the inclusion-exclusion principle for two sets:
$$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$$
Just apply the hint without thinking:
$$\begin{align*}
|A\cup B\cup C| & = |X\cup C| = |X| + |C| - |X\cap C| \\
& = |A\cup B| + |C| - |(A\cup B) \cap C| \\
& = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B| + |C| - |(A\cap C) \cup (B\cap C)| \\
& = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A\cap B| - (|A\cap C| + |B\cap C| - |(A\cap C) \cap (B\cap C)|)
\end{align*}$$
can you finish? (These were actually *three* applications of said rule).

Comment: $=|(A∩C)|+|(B∩C)|−|A∩B∩C|$, but where does the $X=A∪B$ come into this proof besides the begining

Comment: @Csci319 Nowhere. It only servers as a start to make the first application of IEP for two sets more obvious.

Comment: ok, thanks. Was my final answer correct?

Comment: @Csci319 Not quite. Your term is what the parentheses expand to. The final result will be the given formula, of course.

Comment: am I just one step away?

Comment: @Csci319 I'd put your intermediary result as a step before the final one, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: how do I expand it?

Comment: I was thinking $=|A|+|B|-|A∩B∩C|$ then by subtraction rule, $|A∪B∪C|$ or does it not work that way because of the $C$

Comment: No more subtraction rule. Just rearrangement of the terms.

Comment: how do you mean?

Answer (score 6):

$|(A\cup B)\cup C|=|A\cup B|+|C|-|(A\cup B)\cap C|$

Now, $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$

$$\text{and  }|(A\cup B)\cap C|=|(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)|=|(A\cap C)|+|(B\cap C)|-|(A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)|=|(A\cap C)|+|(B\cap C)|-|A\cap B\cap C|$$